# Finding the general solution of a 2nd order ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

SO here's a problem that I'm not having much progress with:

> Using substitution $u=cosx$, how can I find the general solution of
> $sinx(d^2y/dx^2)-cosx(dy/dx)+2ysin^3x=0$

Thank you so much for helping!

My workings so far:

> $(d^2y/dx^2)-(cosx/sinx)(dy/dx)+2ysin^2x=0$
>
> $(du/dx)=-sinx$
>
> $(dy/du)=(dy/dx)(dx/du)=(-1/sinx)(dy/dx)$
>
> $=>(d^2y/dx^2)+u(dy/du)+2ysin^2x=0$
>
> $=>(d^2y/dx^2)+u(dy/du)+2y(1-u^2)=0$

How do I go on further? Is this even the best way to go about the problem??

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You may want to take a look at [the notation help page](/help/notation) to see how to improve your MathJax typesetting. In particular, $\sin, \cos$ are typeset with `\sin, \cos` and $\Rightarrow$ is `\Rightarrow`

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace both the first and second derivatives.

With $u=\cos x$ it holds that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{dy}{du}\sin x
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} & =\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(-\frac{dy}{du}\sin x\Bigr)\\
& =\frac{d^2y}{du^2}\sin^2x -\frac{dy}{du}\cos x\\
& = (1-u^2)\frac{d^2y}{du^2}-u\frac{dy}{du}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin x \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}&-\cos x \frac{dy}{dx}+2y\sin^3 x\\
&=\sin x\Bigl((1-u^2)\frac{d^2y}{du^2}-u\frac{dy}{du}+u\frac{dy}{du}+2y(1-u^2)\Bigr)\\
& = \sin x(1-u^2)\Bigr(\frac{d^2y}{du^2}+2y\Bigr).
\end{aligned}
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: I got a slightly different answer from there...
$(d^2y/du^2)+2y=0$ which is simple to solve in the normal 2nd order ODE fashion :) Thank you so much for the tip! I was having trouble converting the $(d^2y/dx^2)$ factor! :)